# Weighting vs. regression to take into account different auxiliary characteristics of groups

Tags: regression, weighted-mean, weighted-data, weights

I'm interested in comparing different hospitals by their performance in a number of metrics (for example waiting times). Unfortunately the patient characteristics vary between hospitals (hospitals in big cities have usually younger patients and so on) and these mess up the comparison.

The data that I have is of individual visits and the data is complete and not a sample. The amount of individual visits is several millions and even the smaller hospitals have tens of thousands of visits.

It seems that there are two options to get over this problem.

**First**, I can weight the visits in each hospital using the auxiliary variables to make the combined distribution of visits by age group, previous diagnosis and so on equal in each hospital. After this I just calculate weighted averages and compare these.

**Second**, I run a regression analysis for each metric and first put all the auxiliary variables (age group, diagnosis...) as predictors in one block and then add a second block with a dummy coded hospital-variable. By varying the dummy coding I can do comparisons between different individual hospitals, types of hospitals and so on.

Which of the methods would be better and why? Is there some other way to do this even better? Maybe by combining these two methods?

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  Have you considered simply modeling the fact that the two hospitals are very different?  Normalizing the snowfall in Hawaii, Israel, South Africa, and Finland is possible, but the models would be much more representative if you treat them like the different areas that they are.

Comment: In this case the hospitals are actually not that different. They are all within the same country, comply to the same regulation, have almost the same organisational structure and I'm only comparing the same units between each hospital (e.g. cancer wards, emergency care).